# JavaScript Library method on object in variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I've got library. When I use it like `$('#button').value('Click');`, a value `Click` is associated to element with id `button`. 
But when I save it to variable `var button = $('#button');` and I call method `.value('Click')` this way -> `button.value('Click');` it associate Click value to element above it (text input). Why is this happening?

```
(function () {
     var Merge = function (selector) { return Merge.fn.init( selector ); }

Merge.fn = Merge.prototype = {
    map: function ( callback ) {
       var res = [], i = 0;
       for ( ; i < this.length; i++) {
            res.push(callback.call(this, this[i], i));
       }
    },

    each: function ( clbck ) { return this.map(clbck); },

    value: function ( value ) {
        var res = [];
        this.each(function (ma) {
            if (typeof value !== "undefined") { ma.value = value; } else
            { res.push(ma.value); }
        });

       if (typeof value !== "undefined") { return res; }
    }
};

Merge.init = Merge.fn.init = function ( sel ) {
 var el, i = 0;
 if ( typeof sel === "string") { el = document.querySelectorAll(sel); }
 else if (sel.length) { el = sel; } else { el = [sel]; }

 this.length = el.length;
 for (; i < this.length; i++) { this[i] = el[i]; }

 return this;
}
})();
```

in index.php (yes php, I'm using a php too)

```
<script>
(function () {
     var button = $('#button');
     var input = $('#textinput');

     button.value('Click'); // this prints to #textinput
     input.value('Lorem ipsum'); // this is not attached to any element
})();
</script>
```

So I have a problem with "elements" saved in variable and using a method on them.... thx guys

Comment: Please only ask one question per ... question.

Comment: Felix, But do I have to create another topic to ask another question about my library? I mean .. about same thing

Comment: If you have two unrelated issues you should ask two questions.

Comment: edited, are u satisfied?

Comment: Well... it's not clear how the issue you are describing is related to the code you posted. There is not even a `value` method in the code. *"I have a problem with "elements" saved in variable and using a method on them"* And what is that problem? The same as mentioned at the top? It seems very unlikely that such an issue can exist in the first place. Please provide a **complete**, **reproducible** example.

Comment: There is .. but not called ..

Comment: Can't repro the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/s8vcm8eo/

Comment: It's example too .. shortly .. the value that should be in button is attached to element above this button, which is textinput and value that should be attached to textinput is not attached at all

Comment: Ah... now it makes more sense. Why didn't you provide the example to begin with? Because you are calling `Merge.fn.init( selector );` without `new`, `this` refer to the `Merge.fn`. So the second time you call the function, you are simply overriding the existing properties.

Comment: Yes and there was more questions, but you told me I can only one question in one topic .. when I add `new` -> `return new Merge.fn.init(selector);` it prints error in console `button.value is not a function` or when I replace `button` with `$('#button')` it prints `$(...).value is not a function`

Comment: Put differently, both `button` and `input` refer to the same object, `Merge.fn`. *edit:* Well, it seemed liked two issues. If it wasn't then don't remove it. It's on you to present the information in an understandable way. If you know that the issue is because you don't call `new` but you get another error if you use it, then make that clear and ask about that instead.

Comment: and what about that error? _edit:_ so new Question ?